# Do you need to test functionality that has been tested via another test?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, testing

I have a form which processes input and creates a record in my database. I have written some feature tests for the form which include asserting things like validation errors, that a record is successfully inserted into the database and that any relationships are created etc.

The function which processes this data utilises a helper class of sorts which is responsible for performing the validation and creating the record in the database.

To illustrate this:

```php
public function processFormHandler(HelperClass $helper)
{
    // $stuff is some input data from somewhere
    $result = $helper->process($stuff);
}
```

Considering I am performing feature tests on the `processFormHandler`, is it still advisable to perform separate tests against the `HelperClass` or is just testing the `processFormHandler` sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the complexity of your `HelperClass`/`process` method.

If it is really complex or has a lot of dependencies inside `process` method, I would recommend to do a `unit test` just for `process`.

If it is not complex nor has a lot of dependencies, you can totally not test that method.

Remember that when we do a *Feature Test*, we are testing a black box, we input something to a desired part like a URL or a Command or whatever, and we expect something back like a new record, or literal response like JSON or a View or whatever. So if you change that `$helper->process` to code that is not in a class or to other class that does the same or more, for your Feature Test it should still pass and will still that be a black box, it does not matter if `1 + 1` is solved in the same method (`processFormHandler`) or in another class that does 100 billions other things.

So, having that in mind, if you are using this in other places too, I would recommend to create a Unit test so you are 100% sure you are bugs free about it, but if it is really simple and you are working with TDD, do not worry testing it apart from a Feature test.

Comment: The `helper` is used in a few places of the application and I have been testing the functions that use the `helper` which gives me confidence it works. Like you say though, it might be worthwhile testing the `helper` in isolation just to be sure.

Comment: Remember, Feature tests are a must because they test workflows, the most important thing in your app, but unit tests are isolated tests of units, those are important but should be covered if you are testing code that is tested in Feature tests.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you make use of the helper class:

- If you are using the helper output to validate the result, then you are already testing that class/method at the same time. In my opinion, this are my favorite kind of tests since you are validating a functionality from end to end.
- If, on the other hand, you are mocking this helper class to emulate a response, then I'd advise you to create a unit test for the helper on its own. To assure its correct behavior.

Comment: The `helper` is just some code responsible for validating some input, creating a new object and returning that object, or validation errors, to the function that called it. I've tested all the functions that use the `helper` so I am confident it works correctly, but unsure if it is worthwhile testing the `helper` in isolation.

Comment: @themoog then, you already test that functionality. No need to create a separate test for that class.